# ActiveAdmin/Rspec - ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `action_methods' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: rspec, activeadmin

I recently converted my tests from using Cucumber/Capybara to Rspec/Capybara. I am using ActiveAdmin. When I ran tests against ActiveAdmin with Cucumber, the tests run, everything passes. When I run tests with Rspec, I receive:

```
Rendered /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bundler/gems/active_admin-d11c0a56504a/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb (210.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 244ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `action_methods' for nil:NilClass):
    1: insert_tag renderer_for(:index)
  authlogic (3.4.2) lib/authlogic/controller_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:63:in `method_missing'
  /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bundler/gems/active_admin-d11c0a56504a/lib/active_admin/resource/action_items.rb:55:in `block in add_default_action_items'
  /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bundler/gems/active_admin-d11c0a56504a/lib/active_admin/views/action_items.rb:9:in `instance_exec'
  /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bundler/gems/active_admin-d11c0a56504a/lib/active_admin/views/action_items.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in build'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:31:in `block in build_tag'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
  arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:14:in `span'
```

That is only ten lines of the traceback. It's actually much bigger. Let me know if I should paste that.

What is different in rspec that is causing this error?

I am using rspec (2.14.1), activeadmin (master), ruby (2.0), rails (4.1.1).

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Here is my activeadmin resource:

```
ActiveAdmin.register UserPermission, :as => 'Support User' do
  config.batch_actions = false
  config.clear_action_items!
  config.filters = false

  actions :new, :create, :index, :destroy  

  action_item only: [:index] do
    link_to 'Add Support User', new_admin_support_user_path
  end

  controller do
    def scoped_collection
      UserPermission.where(permission: 'support')
    end

    def destroy
      begin
        permission = UserPermission.find_by_id_and_permission!(
        params[:id], UserPermission::SUPPORT)
        permission.destroy if permission.present?
        redirect_to admin_support_users_path, notice: 'Support user removed.'
      rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
        redirect_to admin_support_users_path, alert: 'Support user not found.'
      end
    end

    def create
      user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
      if user
        UserPermission.create(:user_id => user.id,
          :permission => UserPermission::SUPPORT,
          :creator => current_user)
        redirect_to admin_support_users_path, notice: 'Support user added.'
      else
        redirect_to new_admin_support_user_path, alert: 'User not found'
      end
    end
  end

  form partial: "form"

  index :download_links => false do
    column :email do |permission|
      permission.user.email
    end
    column :created_by do |permission|
      if permission.created_by.present?
        u = User.find_by_id(permission.created_by)
        u.email 
      end
    end
    column :created_at
    actions
  end

  menu :parent => 'Users', :priority => 1

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to get back to this and figure it out.  It's a little difficult to pinpoint exactly what the error was saying, but the error is due to a combination of things.

1. config.clear_action_items! - This removed all my controller actions(edit, show, new, create, ...).
2. actions :new, :create, :index, :destroy - This created the only controller actions I wanted.
3. actions in index block (where error was being thrown) - This is attempting to render the default edit, show and destroy actions, which don't all exist, causing the exception.

My fix was to simply not attempt to render those missing actions.  Instead of actions, I now have:

```
actions defaults: false do |permission|
  link_to 'Delete', admin_support_user_path(permission), :method => :delete
end
```

This works.  However, I still don't understand why only rspec had a problem with this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use `default_actions`, or `actions` in your AA model?
`default_actions` is no longer provided in ActiveAdmin 1.x. Use `actions` instead.

Comment: I was using default_actions. I changed it to actions, but am still receiving the above error. This is a step in the right direction though, as removing default_actions/actions causes at least some of my tests to pass. On the other hand, I don't want to remove that line.

Comment: Did you restart your local web server?

Comment: Not sure if I was clear above, but this error is only happening in rspec. The page renders perfectly. The tests run correctly with cucumber. It's only in rspec that I receive this error. What is different in rspec that would be causing this error?